# How do you build a 2D int array from a string array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to build a 2d int array from a string array. I parsed the strings from an input file so that each string had the numbers for the rows of the int array. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?
relevant code:

```
String arrayA[] = ["", 
                  "1 2 -2 0 ",
                  "-3 4 7 2 ",
                  "6 0 3 1 "]
String aryA[] = new String[arrayA.length];
int rowsA[] = new int[3];
int colsA[] = new int[4];
int a[][] = new int[rowsA.length][colsA.length];
String row1A[];
for(int i = 0, j = 1; i < rowsA.length; j++, i++){
    row1A = arrayA[j].split(" ");
    System.out.println(row1A[j]);
    try {
        rowsA[i] = Integer.parseInt(row1A[i]);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Input was not an int");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you get a compile error, as you surely do, you should include the error in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays use braces rather than square brackets

```
String[] arrayA = { "", "1 2 -2 0 ", "-3 4 7 2 ", "6 0 3 1 " };
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code snippet populates 2 dimentional array defined by variable `a` with the contents of `arrayA`:

```
    String arrayA[] = {"", 
                       "1 2 -2 0 ",
                       "-3 4 7 2 ",
                       "6 0 3 1 "};

     int a[][] = new int[3][4];

     for(int i = 0, j = 1; i < arrayA.length-1; j++, i++){
        String[] row1A = arrayA[j].split(" ");  
        for(int k=0; k<row1A.length; k++) {
           System.out.println(row1A[k]);
           try {
                a[i][k] = Integer.parseInt(row1A[k]);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Input was not an int");
            }
        }

     }
```

Comment: This doesn't print the "Input was not an int" for the empty String (first section in the `arrayA`)

Answer (score 0):

Why not import the data from the file into an InputStream and make an ArrayList of ArrayLists instead?

For example:

```
 public void makeAr(){
     public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> my2D = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
     File inputFile = new File("src/main/resources/sample.txt");
     InputStream is = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
     BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
     try {
         while (r.readLine() != null) {
             String row = r.readLine();
             ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
             String row1A[] = row.split(" ");
             for(int q=0;q<row1A.length;q++){
                 ints.add(Integer.parseInt(row1A[q]));
             }
             my2D.add(ints);
         }  
     } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

 }
```

Comment: I'm doing this for a class, but I am about a semester ahead of the rest of the class, and the teacher won't help until the class catches up. P.S. he doesn't actually teach us, he gave us a P.D.F. of  the Blue Pelican Java textbook to work out of and just sits at his desk.

Comment: @Ryuk - This is not an appropriate forum for complaining about your teacher.